# How to implement futimens function in C to change time stamp on file

Tags: c, unix, timestamp

I have written this code using `futimens()` function:

```
int set_time(const char *name)
{
    int dskr = open_file( name );
    struct timespec now;
    int retval = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
    printf("Clock_gettime returned %d \n", retval);
    printf("%ld \n", now.tv_sec);
    
    int status = futimens(dskr, &now);
    handle_error("futimens", status);
    close_file(dskr);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives such output:

```
Clock_gettime returned 0
1619210402
futimens status: -1
futimens() error: Invalid argument
```

ow do I use `futimens` function to change file timestamp to current time?

I am quite new in C so I am really struggling to find needed information to implement the solution.

P.S. `handle_error()` function is just my function to catch exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`futimens` requires an array of two `struct timespec`. That's why you get an invalid argument error. The zeroth element is the access time, and the first is the modification time. So you could set the modification time like this:

```
struct timespec now[2];
now[0].tv_nsec = UTIME_OMIT;
int retval = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now[1]);
int status = futimens(dskr, now);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
struct timespec now[2];
now[0].tv_nsec = UTIME_OMIT;
now[1].tv_nsec = UTIME_NOW;
int status = futimens(dskr, now);
```

See the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/futimens.3p.html).